# how to create invoice automatically validating the "Enter Transfer Details" view

Tags: odoo, invoice

I need to automatically create customer invoice after clicking the designated button of the view in the attached screen capture. I already created a module that overrides the behavior of the button ( it actually just calls the method from super i.e, stock.transfer_details' method do_detailed_transfer() ), but I can't figure out how to create the invoice automatically ( which is done in the next view. after clicking the button, odoo shows Create Invoice view, and I want ro skip that view and do it automatically from code)

[Enter Transfer Details view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzObB.png)

Any ideas ??

EDIT :

Good morning, I figured out how to do it by inspecting the code that creates the invoice from the stock_account module and here is my attempt :

```
def create_invoice(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        picking_pool = self.pool.get('stock.picking')
        inv_ship_obj = self.pool.get('stock.invoice.onshipping')
        data = inv_ship_obj.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context)
        context['date_inv'] = data.invoice_date
        inv_type = 'out_invoice'
        context['inv_type'] = inv_type
        active_ids = context.get('active_ids', [])
        res = picking_pool.action_invoice_create(cr, uid, active_ids,
                                                 journal_id = data.journal_id.id,
                                                 group = data.group,
                                                 type = inv_type,
                                                 context=context)
        return res
```

I just put that method in a class and called it from the method : 
**do_detailed_transfer()**

in case anyone needed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the answer is in the EDIT**

I also had another module showing a form which I deactivated by overriding the method responsible for that.